# Вставка или приложение?

Tags: вставка

Услышав свой диагноз – шизофрения, – я даже обрадовалась.

Услышав свой диагноз – шизофрения, я даже обрадовалась.

Услышав свой диагноз "шизофрения", я даже обрадовалась.

Какое из предложений верное?

И в первом случае обязательные ли кавычки?

Answer (score 6):

**Вариант 1.**  Услышав свой диагноз – шизофрения, – я даже обрадовалась.

Это **вставка**, отнесенная к деепричастному обороту ("перенесенная" запятая).

Сравнить: Заключив тайный договор – его всё-таки пришлось закрепить на бумаге, – великое посольство собралось к отъезду.

**Вариант 2.** Услышав свой диагноз – шизофрения, я даже обрадовалась.

Это обособленное **приложение**, второе тире поглощается запятой.

**Вариант 3.** Услышав свой диагноз "шизофрения", я даже обрадовалась.

Этот вариант имеет нежелательный смысловой оттенок, такое впечатление, что автор уже раньше знал о своем диагнозе, а потом этот диагноз был просто подтвержден.

Из вариантов 1 и 2 лучше смотрится первый вариант со вставкой, он более выразительный, так как имеет большую выделительную способность.